# Need to merge row in slick grid. Need an alternative of rowTemplate() functionality in grid-ui in slick grid.

Tags: slickgrid, angularjs-1.5

We have rowtemplate() in grid-ui, can we have same kind of functionality in slick grid.

I have to merge alternate row and display data in that merged row.

Usage of rowTemplate in grid-ui, I need alternative of this functionality in slick grid.

```
// you could of course just include the template inline in your code, this example shows a template being returned from a function
this.rowTemplate = function() {
    return '<div>' +
        '  <div ng-if="row.entity.merge">{{row.entity.title}}</div>' +
        '  <div ng-if="!row.entity.merge" ng-repeat="(colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.colDef.name" class="ui-grid-cell" ng-class="{ \'ui-grid-row-header-cell\': col.isRowHeader }"  ui-grid-cell></div>' +
        '</div>';           
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't think there's any way to render whole rows, but the column.formatter property can be used to control cell rendering.

Here's an extreme example:
http://6pac.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example8-alternative-display.html

Comment: Thanks @Ben for your solution. I have tried this approach but not fit with our requirement.

Comment: Well, I don't think it will be possible with SlickGrid. There is no control over the rows, which are just collections of <div> elements containing the cells. It is possible to render alternate rows by controlling the cell rendering, but that's the only way possible. Of course, you could always modify the core render code to use a row template. Wouldn't be that hard.

Comment: Thanks @Ben for your solution.